# Firebase Dynamic Link leads to "Dynamic Link not found" when app not installed

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a problem with DynamicLinks. If the app is installed, on an iPhone, the dynamic link opens the iOS app with the deep link and everything works fine. But if the app is not installed, instead of showing the app’s page in the Apple App Store, it shows a web page that says “Dynamic link not found”.

Here is the debug link: https://www.nomadflare.com/app/?ibi=com%2Enomadflare%2ENomadFlare&imv=1%2E0&ofl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Enomadflare%2Ecom&link=https%3A%2F%2Fnomadflare%2Ecom%2Fapp%2F%3Finvitedby%3DdZ3I3pK0KzcOGhO8AoVbBnn8XsO2&d=1

And here is how I configured the whole thing.
In my Firebase project settings, I set the App Store ID and the Team ID:

[image: Project settings in Firebase console]

In my Dynamic Links settings, I defined a new URL prefix with my custom domain and a subpath (I have a website at the root of my domain, hosted on Firebase Hosting):

[image: Dynamic Links settings]

With that I have the following on https://nomadflare.com/apple-app-site-association:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"HLAKBN9F84.com.nomadflare.NomadFlare","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

Then in my XCode project, I enabled Associated Domains in Capabilities, and set a first associated domain to `applinks:$(DYNAMIC_LINKS_DOMAIN)`, where DYNAMIC_LINKS_DOMAIN is a user-defined build setting that depends on the build configuration, but for prod is equal to `nomadflare.com`.

In Info/URL Types, the custom URL scheme is `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` (again, depends on the build configuration, but for prod it's `com.nomadflare.NomadFlare`.

And finally in my Swift code, I have the following function that is triggered when the user taps a Share button:

```swift
    func share() {
        guard let uid = Session.shared.authenticatedUser?.id else {
            return
        }

        guard let customDomains = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains") as? [String],
            let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,
            let websiteUrlString = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "WebsiteUrl") as? String,
            let websiteUrl = URL(string: websiteUrlString),
            let appStoreID = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "AppStoreID") as? String else {
            return
        }

        let urlBase = customDomains[0]
        let link = URL(string: "\(urlBase)/?invitedby=\(uid)")
        let referralLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link!, domainURIPrefix: urlBase)

        referralLink?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: bundleIdentifier)
        referralLink?.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1.0.0"
        referralLink?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = appStoreID

        referralLink?.otherPlatformParameters = DynamicLinkOtherPlatformParameters()
        referralLink?.otherPlatformParameters?.fallbackUrl = websiteUrl

        KRProgressHUD.show()
        referralLink?.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
            KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let invitationUrl = shortURL
            let text = NSLocalizedString("Check out NomadFlare. It's a dating app for travellers and digital nomads.", comment: "")
            let shareAll = [text, invitationUrl!] as [Any]
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

And here are the relevant keys in my Info.plist:

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://$(DYNAMIC_LINKS_DOMAIN)/app</string>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<key>WebsiteUrl</key>
<string>$(WEBSITE_URL)</string>
<key>AppStoreID</key>
<string>1474350816</string>
```

And `WEBSITE_URL` is yet another build-config-specific user-defined setting, whose value is `https://www.nomadflare.com` in production.

I'm really not sure about what I put in the `link` part of my referral link though.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you fixed it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You also have to  set the app store id of your app and iTunes parameter in dynamic link .Thank you

Comment: How? Can you hint some example? (The problem is not the "what" but the "how" )

Answer (score 0):

The first link in the question has the ibi query parameter, which is the bundle ID. However, it also needs "[Your app's App Store ID, used to send users to the App Store when the app isn't installed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually#:%7E:text=Your%20app%27s%20App%20Store%20ID%2C%20used%20to%20send%20users%20to%20the%20App%20Store%20when%20the%20app%20isn%27t%20installed)", which is the isi query parameter, which should be 1474350816 according to the screenshot above (i.e. add `&isi=1474350816` to the long link).  Refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually for more detailed instructions.